# Azure CloudBlockBlob.Exists() method always returns false

Tags: c#, azure

So I have uploaded a file into my Azure storage account and now I am trying to delete it, so I have the method.

```
try
{
    var exists = Blob.Exists(); //Always False
    var t = Blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots, null, null, new OperationContext());
    if (!t.Result) // t.Result is Always False
    {
         Blob.DeleteAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots, null, null, new OperationContext());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //No 404 error thrown for DeleteAsync (Proves blob must exist)
}
```

but my `Blob.Exists()` method always returns false even though I can see the blob in my storage account through the portal. What does the Exist method actually do? The only information [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.exists.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) gives is:

> Checks existence of the blob.

After the `DeleteIfExistsAsync` method returns false because apparently the blob doesn't exist I use `DeleteAsync` and this removes the file from my storage account, also more importantly doesn't throw a 404 error which is ususally thrown if no blob is there to delete or access permissions are incorrect.

why do `Blob.Exists` and `Blob.DeleteIfExists` always return false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a problem with my `SharedAccessSignature` previously I had

```
var sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
          {
              Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete,
              SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharedAccessSignatureExpiryTimeOffset"]))
          });
```

but I needed to add `SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read` to my `SharedAccessSignature`. With the extra read permission `Exists()` now returns true